assignin() is not working inside mask initialization code
I am trying to add a Simulink.signal variable in 'base' workspace within a block's mask initialization code using assignin () function. Now, this is quite unsuccessful and to my surprise I am not seeing any errors in the command window, also the intended Simulink signal object is not present in the 'base' workspace. The block is also a part of Simulink library. I have read some matlab better practice not to define data objects withing mask initialization code but should rely on model callback. This issue is happening to me in 2022b matlab version.
I need this signal definition to implement a datastore and to reuse at multiple places of the main model.

"should be a part of library" -- all the more reason not to write stuff to the base workspace. Other than that, it is quite unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish.

I think I should refactor the question, sorry it didn't come out the way I intended

Try showing us instead of telling us what you're trying to do, show us some code as well as relevant screenshots of your model to better illustrate what you're trying to accomplish as a [mcve]. This also sounds like a bit of an xy problem because you're asking us to fix something about how you've approached this, while also suggesting your approach should maybe be totally different - try to contextualise what your intended end result is
